# How to retrieve id of anchor tags in console using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the respective id of anchor tags.

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px"></div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown-container" style="display:inline-block; padding-left:10px;">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Party ID
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-check1" aria labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#" id="class">class ID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="subject">subject Number</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

I have written this code to fetch the id :

```
console.log($("#dropdown-container a").parents('.dropdown-menu').attr('id'))
```

But this is retrieving the value "dropdown-check1" instead of the respective anchor tags.
What should I do to get an id of the respective anchor tags?

Comment: Don't go back up to the dropdown-menu?

Comment: `$(...).parents('.dropdown-menu').attr('id');` is targeting the `<ul>` element, and retrieving it's `id`, exactly as you specified. If you want the ids of that parent's children `<a>` tags, try `.find('a').attr('id');` (although `.parents` is unnecessary altogether)

Comment: the `parents` method make you go back to the `ul` element. just remove `.parents('.dropdown-menu')`

Comment: It worked, but on switching to Subject, I am still getting 'class' instead of 'subject'.It should change based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: Please show full code context as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the ids of all the `a` inside the `dropdown-container`, you can use the below code.

```
$("#dropdown-container a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

To access the id of the anchor tag only when it is clicked.

```
$("#dropdown-container").on('click', 'a', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$("#dropdown-container a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});

$("#dropdown-container").on('click', 'a', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px"></div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown-container" style="display:inline-block; padding-left:10px;">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Party ID
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-check1" aria labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#" id="class">class ID</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="subject">subject Number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
jQuery('#dropdown-check1 a').each(function(){var x= jQuery(this).attr('id');console.log(x);});
```

Then let me know the result.

Comment: I don't want value of all the anchor tags.If I click on Subject, it should just fetch me Subject and If I switch to Class ,then it should just fetch me class instead of both .What changes should I make?